# ./activetenant' does not contain an export named 'ActiveTenant'

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use a component that is already created, but I cant figure out what the problem is:

activetenant

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import authAction from '../../redux/auth/actions';

class ActiveTenant extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}
export default ActiveTenant;
```

and the component where I am trying to use it

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Layout } from "antd";
import appActions from "../../redux/app/actions";
import TopbarUser from "./topbarUser";
import TopbarWrapper from "./topbar.style";
import themes from "../../settings/themes";
import { themeConfig } from "../../settings";
import { ActiveTenant } from "./activetenant";

const { Header } = Layout;
const { toggleCollapsed } = appActions;
const customizedTheme = themes[themeConfig.theme];

class Topbar extends Component {
  render() {
    const { toggleCollapsed } = this.props;
    const collapsed = this.props.collapsed && !this.props.openDrawer;
    const styling = {
      background: customizedTheme.backgroundColor,
      position: "fixed",
      width: "100%",
      height: 70
    };
    return (
      <TopbarWrapper>
        <Header
          style={styling}
          className={
            collapsed ? "isomorphicTopbar collapsed" : "isomorphicTopbar"
          }
        >
          <div className="isoLeft">
            <button
              className={
                collapsed ? "triggerBtn menuCollapsed" : "triggerBtn menuOpen"
              }
              style={{ color: customizedTheme.textColor }}
              onClick={toggleCollapsed}
            />
          </div>

          <ul className="isoRight">
            <li>
              <ActiveTenant />
            </li>
            <li
              onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedItem: "user" })}
              className="isoUser"
            >
              <TopbarUser />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </Header>
      </TopbarWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    ...state.App.toJS()
  }),
  { toggleCollapsed }
)(Topbar);
```

And the error

> ./src/containers/Topbar/Topbar.js 105:34-46 './activetenant' does not
>   contain an export named 'ActiveTenant'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are use `export default ActiveTenant` In this case code should be like this

```
import ActiveTenant  from "./activetenant";
```

If you want to export mulitple value then use `{}` to import

for example 
//test.js

```
var a = "cool";
var b = "dool";
export a;
export b;

import {a,b} from './test.js'
```